# Eclipse javascript autocompletion

Tags: javascript, jquery, eclipse, jsp, autocomplete

I am editing a *.jsp* file, and I inserted a `<script>` html tag, specifying the path of the *jquery.js* file, then in the next `<script>` tag, I am trying to use JQuery methods, but it has not autocompletion.

[image]

**How do I enable autocompletion for JavaScript in HTML/JSP files?** I am currently using Web Tools Project, but I am willing to download any other addon if required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should have a look to this eclipse plugin https://github.com/angelozerr/angularjs-eclipse and most specifically this one https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java

I use it for angularjs and JS autocompletion. You can add autocompletion on jQuery and other common libraries.

To install and use it, look https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/wiki.

Comment: Could you please tell me, which specific packages do I have to install? And how do you enable JavaScript external libraries autocompletion? (atleast JQuery)?

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice your comment. You should install at least Tern Feature, Tern JSDT Feature, Tern Server node.js feature, Tern Tooling. You can also install WTP HTML - Web resources for a nice autocomplete on css class.
Here is the getting started page https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/wiki/Getting-Started

Comment: Once you have installed tern.java, you can activate jQuery support with Tern Modules project properties. See https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/wiki/Tern-&-jQuery-support